# How to extend external javascript library with angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I've added moment into my project and I would like to know how can I change the behavior of `moment.fn.toJSON` globally.

Currently, I'm using the constructor to do so and it works. But I don't want to paste this code in all of my controllers.

So here is an extract :

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    moment.fn.toJSON = function () { return this.format(); }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: add this to your main.ts or polyfills.ts, or create an abstract class that your components inherit from.

Comment: I've finally done with a service instead. It's still not what I would like to do but it works fine. Your solution seems great, I will have to look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just extend the class in the 3rd party library and add your custom methods as required.

For example:

//1) Extend the class:

```
 export class MyFormBuilder extends FormBuilder{

     public myCoolMethod(): string{
        return "Awesome stuff!"
     }
 }
```

//2) Import your class into the "application module" (for system-wide access)

```
import { MyFormBuilder }     from './Services/MyFormBuilder';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, AppHeader, AppFooter],
    imports:      [BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    providers:    [MyFormBuilder],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
})
```

`

//3) Import, inject and use your extended class and new methods in your code:

```
import { MyFormBuilder }     from './Services/MyFormBuilder';
export class AppComponent{
    constructor(private fb: MyFormBuilder){}
    pageTitle : string = this.fb.myCoolMethod();
}
```